# nixos 'loadkeys dvorak' by default

Tags: nixos, dvorak

I am setting up nixos.

Each time I change my configuration.nix and run `nixos-rebuild switch`, I must run the command `loadkeys dvorak` in order to use my preferred keyboard.

How can I configure nixos to load the dvorak keymap automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the configuration option: `i18n.consoleKeyMap = "dvorak";`